# How to get a -0 result in floating point calculations and distinguish it from +0 in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, zero

The MSDN documentation mentions that `double` type includes negative zero. However, both `-1.0 / double.PositiveInfinity` and `-double.Epsilon / 2` appear to return normal 0 (and compare equal to it). How can I get -0?

Comment: Okay, I'm curious: since they're mathematically the same value, why do you want to distinguish +0 from -0?

Comment: Because I want to show the differences between normal mathematical calculations and floating point calculations.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a practical example of differentiating between the two without examining the bits.  MSDN links [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691146(VS.71).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(VS.71).aspx) assisted me in constructing this example.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float a = 5 / float.NegativeInfinity;
    float b = 5 / float.PositiveInfinity;
    float c = 1 / a;
    float d = 1 / b;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.WriteLine(d);
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
-Infinity
Infinity
```

Take note that -0 and 0 both look the same for comparisons, output, etc.  But if you divide 1 by them, you get a -Infinity or Infinity, depending on which zero you have.

Comment: > Take note that -0 and 0 both look the same for comparisons, output, etc.

Thanks, that's what I missed.

Answer (score 3):

Negative zero is to do with the way that the number is stored in binary, not any real achievable result from a mathematical calculation.

In floating point storage, the topmost bit is often used to denote sign. This leaves 31 bits for data (in a 32bit floating point value) so there are actually two representations for zero.

00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Or
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001

Both represent zero, but one with the sign bit set to negative.

Naturally, this would normally occur when you incremented the highest possible positive number, it would overflow back to negative zero.

In .net however I think by default the type does overflow checks and will throw an exception rather than let you overflow, so the only way to really archive this value is by setting it directly. Also, -0 should always compare equal to +0.

There is more about it on [Wikipeida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%88%920_(number))

Comment: Actually, Wiki says "whilst it is possible to obtain negative zero as the result of an expression (for instance as the result of arithmetic underflow on a negative number)" for languages including C#.

Comment: "arithmetic underflow on a negative number" - Yeah, that's just the reverse of overflow of the highest positive number in my example. Anyway Brian's answer is much better than mine, listen to him =:)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the BitConverter.GetBytes. If you check the bytes, you will see that the sign bit for the value is actually set indicating that its negative.

```
byte[] zeroBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(zero);
byte[] negZeroBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(negZero);

bool sameBytes = zeroBytes[7] == negZeroBytes[7];
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Firstly, zero & negZero, what are they? Secondly, if I make them doubles and set the values 0 & -0, I just get an array of bytes that are all 0 for both.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. If `pz` is positive zero and `nz` is negative zero:

```
Double.PositiveInfinity/pz => Double.PositiveInfinity
Double.PositiveInfinity/nz => Double.NegativeInfinity
```

I got this from [ECMA C# specification](http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_standard/14.7.2.htm).

You can obtain negative zero by dividing any positive number by negative infinity:

```
10.0/Double.NegativeInfinity
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking, I see that `-1.0 / double.PositiveInfinity` *does* return -0. Indeed, `1.0 / (-1.0 / double.PositiveInfinity)` returns `-infinity`.