# Is there any reason this isn't redundant code?

Tags: c#, .net, redundancy, absolute-value

I came across this code in some existing codebase:

```
double rad = ComputeCurviness();
double off = Math.Abs(rad);
if (rad < 0) off = -off;
```

It seems to be basically just making `off` equal to `rad`.  The variables are used interchangeably later in the code.  Is there any reason to leave this code in?

Comment: Nope, but `double off` and `double rad` are awesome.

Comment: ...all of a sudden, my head really hurts.

Comment: `off` is probably there just in case `rad` does not compute!

Comment: My tendency, before claiming it is 100%, is to check outliers (NaN, +/-Infinity, MaxValue, MinValue).  I couldn't find any cases where it broke, but I didn't check that carefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `rad` is -0.0, `off` will be +0.0. You'd have to inspect the code to see whether this would actually make a difference. The two are equivalent when it comes to calculations and comparisons, but -0.0 is negative, which you can detect if you try hard enough.

Comment: Who was such a downer that even *zero* had to be expressable as a negative?

Comment: +1 Ack, I forgot to check +/- 0 when thinking about outliers.  Nice catch.  I posted sample code to differentiate between +/- 0 in response to another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043816/how-to-get-a-0-result-in-floating-point-calculations-and-distinguish-it-from-0/1043909#1043909