# Check empty element array of double c#

Tags: c#, arrays, double, element

I'm looking for a code to check if an element of my array of double is empty. I tried with `isNaN`, `string.isNullOrEmpty` and `0.0D` but nothing to do, I still have this text : Not a Number.

So, do you know any code in C# which is able to check if an element in a an array of double is empty?

Here is my code:

```
if (!Double.IsNaN(d1.getChiffreAffaireBase()[keyIndex1]))
{
    textBox43.Text = calcMargeCa(d1.getChiffreAffaireBase()[keyIndex1], d1.getChiffreAffairePlus()[keyIndex1]).ToString("0.00");
    textBox44.Text = calcMargeCa(d1.getChiffreAffaireBase()[keyIndex1+1], d1.getChiffreAffairePlus()[keyIndex1+1]).ToString("0.00");
}
else
{
    label13.Hide();
    textBox43.Hide();
    textBox44.Hide();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *empty*? `double` is a ValueType, it cannot be "empty".

Comment: Post your code then we'll have a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have double[] array = new double[12] and I want to check if array[6]for example has no values.

Comment: @VincentNormand edit your code into the question, not in a comment. also add the code you are using to check the array element.

Comment: It will always have a value because as @FrédéricHamidi said, value types always have values.

Comment: You can use `if (array[6] != null)`

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR this is always `true` as `double` is a value type that can never be `null`.

Comment: If you have `double[] array = new double[12]`, the array will have 12 values. They can be NaN, or 0.0 (or any other `double` value), but there is no such thing as "empty".

Answer (score 5):

if you declare an array like this

```
double[] array = new double[12];    // elements cannot be null
```

all elements will be set to `0`.

Declare it as `nullable`, if you really want

```
var array = new double?[12];    // elements can be null
var isEmpty = (array[6] == null);
```

or

```
var isEmpty = !array[6].HasValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

[Value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) cannot *not have* a value (that is to say, they cannot be `null`) but you could use a [`Nullable<double>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) (or `double?` for short) which can be set to `null` if you want to indicate that it doesn't have a value. Here's an example:

```
double?[] array = new double?[12];
```

then for checking if it has a value you compare it to `null`:

```
if (array[6] == null){
    // do your thing
}
```

**Edit:**

Off topic but now that you've posted your code I see that you're using `double` to represent money (Chiffre d'Affaire or Revenue) while that could work, you should [use `decimal` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1165761/162671)

Answer (score 1):

Double.IsNaN doesn't check for null values , check this for more or read the documentations about it
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967190/6001737

instead you can use `double?[] array = new double?[12];` which is Nullable and you can then check if a certain array value equals null